# How do I compile mlt to use ffmpeg?

Tags: mlt

ffmpeg compiles fine, and so does mlt.

And melt works fine with color:green and the like, but cannot open .asf video files, however ffplay plays them fine.

I've tried the following but mlt still won't play an asf file:

```
./configure --enable-gpl3 --enable-gpl --avformat-shared=/big/src/ffmpeg/libavformat/

./configure --enable-gpl3 --enable-gpl 

./configure
```

When I try to play the asf file, like this, I get this:

```
bash-4.3$ melt /big/video-coon.asf 
Failed to load "/big/video-coon.asf"
Failed to load "/big/video-coon.asf"
Usage: melt [options] [producer [name=value]* ]+
Options:
  -attach filter[:arg] [name=value]*       Attach a filter to the output
[snip]
For more help: <http://www.mltframework.org/>
```

I would be most grateful if someone could provide me a clue on how to get mlt to read these files!

I tried converting the .asf file to a .dv file with ffmpeg (that makes it huge!) but that would not play in melt either. (Played with ffplay/mplayer however.)

Thanks very much,

Jesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it working.. I think.
Granted, there was an instance when I couldn't even get ffmpeg to build (it was saying something needed to be compiled with -fPIC) but then I uninstalled (make uninstall) mlt, then a make clean and reconfigure on ffmpeg got it going again.

So as best as I can tell, here's the trick for getting ffmpeg and mlt to build from source on slackware 14.2 64bit with multilib:

Note that in my case, I have a /usr/lib and a /usr/lib64/ and some libs in each.

My PKG_CONFIG_PATH did not include /usr/lib/pkgconfig/ which is where ffmpeg's installation was putting libavformat.pc, so pkg-config could not find it, so mlt was thinking ffmpeg was not installed, so to fix that I had to make sure the environment variable was set:

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/lib/pkgconfig/`

Furthermore, some components of libavformat seemed to be in one lib directory, and others in the other, so I had to also set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$D_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64`

Once that was set up, I suggest going to the mlt source folder and typing `make uninstall` if you've previously tried to install, in case it interferes with the compiling of ffmpeg. (Yeah yeah, I know it shouldn't be needed but I've had some weirdness tonight so I'm just telling you.)

Same goes for ffmpeg - `make uninstall` if you'd had unhappy attempts to install it.

1: cd to the source directory for ffmpeg.

2: run `./configure --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 && make -j8 && make install`.

3: If that goes well, then cd to the source directory for mlt.

4: run `make clean && ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-gpl3 && make -j8 && make install`

Some important points:

1: ffmpeg must be built with --enable-shared for mlt to use it.

2: mlt needs $PKG_CONFIG_PATH to be set up fully to detect ffmpeg during ./configure.

3: mlt needs $LD_LIBRARY_PATH set correctly at runtime.

Of course all this may be specific to the particular version of ffmpeg and mlt that was the latest at the time of writing, but maybe it'll help somebody.